# Execute the output of a Python script as Windows script commands

Tags: python, windows, batch-file

I'm trying to set up an elegant way of defining a Windows environment, based on varying configuration files, before executing a program. I am not calling the program execution myself (which would make things easier) but am only inserting the correct environment into an existing automated process.

I could write `setenv.bat` files for each possible configuration but would much prefer parsing a `config.yml` that will be used in other scenarios, too.

A Pyton script felt like the way to go. But environment variables set in Python will be lost after returning from the Python process.

I'm now using Python as a converter/generator to create batch commands from the config. Let `python cmd_from_cfg.py config.yml` output something like this:

```
SET "ENV_VAR_A=config-value"
SET "ENV_VAR_B=config-value"
CALL "path-from-config.bat"
```

This can be redirected to a file and executed:

```
python cmd_from_cfg.py config.yml > setenv.bat
setenv.bat
program.exe
```

But what I really want to do (and had hoped would be easy) is skip the creation of `setenv.bat` and immediately **execute the Python script results as Windows commands**. Is this possible?

I tried this but it stops each line as soon as a whitespace is reached:

```
FOR %%i IN ('python cmd_from_cfg.py config.yml') ECHO %%i
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply run a for loop to grab all the output for the external command.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('python cmd_from_cfg.py config.yml') do echo %%A
```

You would need to remove `echo` to actually perform the commands.

Comment: This is potentially a source of mojibake because Python defaults to writing ANSI to a pipe and CMD's `for /f` loop defaults to decoding line by line using the current console codepage, which defaults to OEM. The Python script and batch script need to agree on the encoding. Preferably this should be UTF-8 (e.g. `chcp.com 65001` in CMD, and set `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8` for Python and print `unicode` strings) to be able to handle any Unicode character.

Answer (score 1):

Batch executes any environment variable expanded without echo. For example:

```
set "CMD=echo hi"
%CMD%
```

Will print:

```
hi
```

You need to capture the output of your Python script and then expand each variable as it is. Considering your script has three lines in output:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
set "COUNTER=1"
for /f "delims=" %%k in ('python generator.py config.yml') do (
set "VARIABLE!COUNTER!=%%k"
set /A COUNTER+=1
)
!VARIABLE1!
!VARIABLE2!
!VARIABLE3!
ENDLOCAL
```

[More about DelayedExpansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html).

Comment: `delims` is used to mark the delimiters. In above case no delimiter means only new lines. I was not sure about your requirement so I exported them outside `for` loop.